# Validar fechas de rangos

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

He estado peleando con una query de postgreSQL, en donde me han pedido que valide que la fecha, ya sea de inicio o fin, no este en el rango establecido. En caso de que no, devolver true, sino devolver un false
He armado mi query pero siempre me devuelve un false, aunque la fecha que utilizo no se encuentre en el rango establecido.

**Mi consulta:**

```sql
select case when count(*)=0 then 'true' else 'false' end from price."COMMISSIONS_RANGES" wek 
where DATE(:startDate) between wek."START_DATE" and wek."END_DATE" 
or DATE(:endDate) between wek."START_DATE" and wek."END_DATE"
```

Invocacion de mi query:
Repository:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Service:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla:
En este caso he estado probando con el id 75
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la atención y la ayuda!

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías añadir cómo invocas a tu query y, si puede ser, la definición de la tabla?

Comment: Listo! Espero que te pueda servir lo editado.

Comment: Podrías indicar, con un ejemplo, ¿cómo haces la invocación a la query? ¿Con qué datos invocas?

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿buscas tanto los rangos que abarcan un rango completo, como los que están fuera del rango? ¿O solo uno de los anteriores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo disculpa esta respuesta pues podría ser un comentario pero mi rango me lo impide.

Entendiendo que el enfoque de la solución del problema es mirar si existe dentro de esos rangos y luego negar el resultado de esta consulta, creo que el nexo en el Where debería ser AND

```
select case when count(*)=0 then 'true' else 'false' end from price."COMMISSIONS_RANGES" wek 
where DATE(:startDate) between wek."START_DATE" and wek."END_DATE" 
AND DATE(:endDate) between wek."START_DATE" and wek."END_DATE"
```

Según las [Leyes de Morgan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyes_de_De_Morgan) la negación de la conjunción

> ```
> ¬ ( P ∧ Q ) ⟺ ( ¬ P ) ∨ ( ¬ Q ) 
> ¬ ( P ∨ Q ) ⟺ ( ¬ P ) ∧ ( ¬ Q )
> ```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de todas formas! Lo aplicare para ver como funciona su solucion. Le agradezco nuevamente